# CSS element dropping below expected position in Safari

Tags: css, css-float, safari

I have an issue whereby I have a block of color that I use like a button that sits nicely in Firefox and IE but for some reason in Safari sits below where I want it to sit (see image).

[image]

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated as I've fiddled with this for awhile and can't seem to get it to work (?)

The (what I think is) relevant CSS is:

```
//the element that represents the button that is floating
//too low in safari:

#addplacebtn {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0em;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 35px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #226083;

}

//the element that is containing the problematic element

#edit-addplacebtn {
 height: 45px;
 width: 35px;
 top: 5px;

}

//the element containing the above element

.tbrow {
 height: 35px;
 width: 285px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that for some reason, the button doesn't quite fit in the gap you've left for it. Aside from that, you've got both `display: inline-block;` and `float: right;` on `#addplacebtn`. `float` means `display` will have no effect. Maybe try `float:left;`? Also, unless you've positioned `#edit-addplacebtn`, `top` will have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can try to set the position to Absolute. this will ensure that it will stick to one position.

```
position:absolute;
```

Second instead of margin, you should try left and top. cuz margin isnt the same in all browsers.

```
left: 400px;
top: 350px;
```

It is a lot of trying and cursing to get the elements where they should be in as many browsers, it just is :)

i hope this helps!! :)

ps. (sorry for bad english i hope you understand me xD)

Comment: please be aware that using position:absolute; on a child element will need position:relative; in the parent

Comment: I can get the button to sit on the same line but only if I reduce the width to 30px. I tried to editing the width of the container and the element itself and despite there seeming to be plenty of room for the element to fit it just doesn't work in Safari. I haven't tried position absolute yet however. I noticed the font size of the + symbol is 30px. Im wondering if that's just a coincidence (?)

Comment: Well, I got this exact same problem in a responsive website. I wonder if I write "position:absolute;" will make that the web site's responsiveness stops working on those items?

Comment: The comment by @PhilipBevan should appear as a floating div in every question about css positioning.